# Swift .isNaN Understand how it works

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently facing an issue in understanding how .isNan works.

I am maintaining an application which is not developed (in Swift 2.3) by myself.

We have a nice amount of crashes from this code, and from my understanding I don't understand how.

Here is the method, which is simply a format method in order to set the appropriate value to your label by testing different cases.

```
    static func formatFloat(float: Float?, withMaxDigits
max: Int, andUnit unit: String) -> String {

            var label: String = "-"

            if let float = float {

                let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
                numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
                numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
                numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = max
                numberFormatter.roundingMode = .RoundHalfUp

                if !float.isNaN {
                    var formattedValue = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(float)!
                    if(formattedValue == "-0")
                    {
                        formattedValue = "0"
                    }
                    label = "\(formattedValue) \(unit)"
                }
            }

            return label
        }
```

Am I right that it justs check to determine whether a value is NaN or not, in order to test everything, and set the text accordingly ?

I read some posts/documentations and I don't understand this :

> In some languages NaN != NaN, but this isn't the case in Cocoa.

What about nil and NaN ? I mean isNan check for false right ?

Comment: You already know that `float` isn't nil since it was conditionally unwrapped. Personally I would conditionally unwrap the `stringFromNumber` rather than forcing it and remove the isNaN test

Comment: So var formattedValue = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber!(float)
without the isNan test is cleaner ?

Comment: Yes, but `if let formattedValue = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(float) {...`

Comment: You mean if var no ? I cannot assign value to the let constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IEEE floating point spec documents certain bit patterns that represent NaN invalid results.

nil is different from a NaN. In Swift, only an optional can contain nil, and it indicates the absence of a value.

a NaN means you performed some operation that resulted in an invalid result. You should check the `isNaN` property to see if a number contains a NaN.

### Edit:

Note that there are different values that are marked as `NaN`, so one `.NaN` value may not be equal to another `.NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

No, `nan` is a value that a floating point can take. `nil` can only be taken by optional vars. Also I'm not sure where you got that quote, but `.nan == .nan` is false. For more information read https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/floatingpoint

Comment: "Comparing a NaN with any value, including another NaN, results in false."
Thank you for that part